# how do i tweak my edges so that they may result in a perfect circle?

Tags: modeling

Please don't tell me i have to select every individual edge and tweak it with the mouse i don't want to do that. I've tried everything i know.[image]

Comment: Hello :). There are tools to make vertices into a circle, but you'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for the two rods being in connection with the spheroid, then use bevel and select check box - autosmooth in the "normals" settings. Also add shade smooth to the rods. This hides the angles a lot.  But this is normally done by boolean "brush" using bool tool or boolean in general selecting union. Brush is preferred for alterations - non-destructive.  Look up curved booleans.  Right click to add shade smooth, and autosmooth is in the side bar.  After this if the action still does not work, adjust the added bevel modifier to angle or weight, also move the boolean up or down in the modifier stack depending on if you still have a bad result.  Normally boolean first.

If it is to get a better sphere you may have to use a cast of a sphere and apply.  CG boost has 100 tips video showing this process.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is those edges circular you can enable looptools (one of the built in addons) and just right click and select circle.

[image]